# How to move canvas objects each time I click the button?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a game and I have the blocks spawning randomly in the grid in the one fixed row (for example row 5 [horizontally]). Every time I click the button I want the blocks to move from row 5 to row 4(vertically). And then I want the new random blocks to generate on row 5 and so on. How can I do this? Right now it only spawning the new blocks under the first row (on the row 6, then 7 and so on).

[image: screenshot for the visual reference]

```js
//Accessing canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('grid');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var w = ctx.canvas.width;
var h = ctx.canvas.height;

// Drawing grid
var drawingGrid = function() {

  for (x = 0; x <= w; x += 60) {
    for (y = 0; y <= h; y += 60) {

      // Gray grid
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#cccccc";
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, h);
      ctx.moveTo(0, y);
      ctx.lineTo(w, y);

      if (x % 240 === 0) {
        // Black X-axis grid |
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";


        if (x === 0 || x === 480) {
          ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        } else {
          ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        }
        // Middle vertical line
        if (x === 240) {
          // 0-480
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(x, 480);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#222831";
          ctx.stroke();

          // 480-560
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(x, 480);
          ctx.lineTo(x, 540);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#cccccc";
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';

        } else {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(x, h);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#222831";
        }



      } else if (y % 240 === 0 || y === 540) {
        // Black Y-axis grid _
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#222831";

        if (y === 0 || y === 540) {
          ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        } else if (y === 480) {
          ctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
        } else {
          ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, y);
        ctx.lineTo(h, y);

      }
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }



};

drawingGrid(480, 540, 'grid');

// Starting coordinates
var posX = 0;
var posY = 240;
// Move blocks on Y axis
function moveY(){
  posY +=60;
}
// Spawn random amount of blocks on the field
function gener(){
  posX = 60*Math.floor(8*Math.random());
}

  function spawnRandomObject() {

    // Game Object
      ctx.fillStyle = '#f2a365';
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, 60, 60);
      ctx.stroke();
  }

// Blocks moving up
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Spawn random amount of objects
  for (var i=0; i<Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1)*2; i++){
    gener();
    spawnRandomObject();

  }
moveY();
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #ececec;
}

canvas{
  padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

.row{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.firstrow{
  width:20%;
}

.mainrow{
  width:60%;
  display: block;
}

.thirdrow{
  width: 20%;
}

.header{
  background-color: #222831;
  color: #ececec;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container{
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.thirdrow{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Shmetris</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Shmetris</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">

  <!-- Controls -->
    <div class="row first">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Score: 0</h1>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="button">Refresh</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Game Area -->
    <div class="row mainrow">
      <div class="col-" id="gamearea">
   
          

        <!-- Canvas -->
        <canvas id="grid" width="480" height="540" style="background: #ececec "></canvas>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!--  -->
    <div class="row thirdrow">
      <div class="col" style="text-align:left;">
        

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Script -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aren't you missing to remove the previously spawned blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed your `moveY()` function and added the `moveRow()` function. The game objects (the rects) are saved to a list `objects`. Their y position is increased on each button click. The old drawn positions are removed, the new positions are drawn. Then the randomly generated blocks are added in the 5th row.

Note that the `clearRect()` function inside the `removeCell()` also removes parts of the grid. This causes to redraw the grid every time. You can improve the code by splitting your grid creation in using a sub function which draws the grid on only one cell. Then you can redraw the grid only on those cells that are needed. This probably is a performance boost and makes the code more beautiful in my eyes, but it works like this too.

I also suggest to use `length` instead of `60` and calculate the thicker grid lines by the length, e.g. `8 * length` instead of `480` and so on.

```js
//Accessing canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('grid');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var w = ctx.canvas.width;
var h = ctx.canvas.height;

// Drawing grid
var drawingGrid = function() {

  for (x = 0; x <= w; x += 60) {
    for (y = 0; y <= h; y += 60) {

      // Gray grid
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#cccccc";
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, h);
      ctx.moveTo(0, y);
      ctx.lineTo(w, y);

      if (x % 240 === 0) {
        // Black X-axis grid |
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";


        if (x === 0 || x === 480) {
          ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        } else {
          ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        }
        // Middle vertical line
        if (x === 240) {
          // 0-480
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(x, 480);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#222831";
          ctx.stroke();

          // 480-560
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(x, 480);
          ctx.lineTo(x, 540);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#cccccc";
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';

        } else {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(x, h);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#222831";
        }



      } else if (y % 240 === 0 || y === 540) {
        // Black Y-axis grid _
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#222831";

        if (y === 0 || y === 540) {
          ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        } else if (y === 480) {
          ctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
        } else {
          ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, y);
        ctx.lineTo(h, y);

      }
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }



};

drawingGrid(480, 540, 'grid');

var length = 60;
// Starting coordinates
var posX = 0;
var posY = 4 * length;
var objects = []

function moveRows(){
  for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
    // remove old objects
    removeCell(objects[i][0], objects[i][1]);
    // move objects
    objects[i][1] += length;
  }
  
  drawingGrid();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
    // redraw objects on new location
    drawCell(objects[i][0], objects[i][1]);
  }
}
// Spawn random amount of blocks on the field
function gener(){
  posX = length*Math.floor(8*Math.random());
}

  function spawnRandomObject() {

    // Game Object
    drawCell(posX, posY);
    objects.push([posX, posY]);
  }

function drawCell(x, y, color){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#f2a365";
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, length, length);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function removeCell(x, y){
    ctx.clearRect(x, y, length, length);
}

// Blocks moving up
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Spawn random amount of objects
  moveRows();
  for (var i=0; i<Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1)*2; i++){
    gener();
    spawnRandomObject();

  }
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #ececec;
}

canvas{
  padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

.row{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.firstrow{
  width:20%;
}

.mainrow{
  width:60%;
  display: block;
}

.thirdrow{
  width: 20%;
}

.header{
  background-color: #222831;
  color: #ececec;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container{
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.thirdrow{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Shmetris</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Shmetris</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">

  <!-- Controls -->
    <div class="row first">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Score: 0</h1>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="button">Refresh</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Game Area -->
    <div class="row mainrow">
      <div class="col-" id="gamearea">
   
          

        <!-- Canvas -->
        <canvas id="grid" width="480" height="540" style="background: #ececec "></canvas>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!--  -->
    <div class="row thirdrow">
      <div class="col" style="text-align:left;">
        

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Script -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```